# Не до конца проматывает scrollTo

Tags: android, прокрутка

Здравствуйте.

У меня есть Activity, в котором я подгружаю fragment, а потом пытаюсь промотать его до самого низа, но scrollTo не доходит до конца ровно на высоту моего fragment. 
Пробовала:

```
scrollView.scrollTo(scrollView.getHeight());
scrollView.scrollTo(0,100500);
scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
```

Собственно, вопрос - как промотать окно до низа?

Comment: Покажите больше кода, где вызываете?

Comment: Вызываю в самом конце, после показа всего. (Там очень-очень много кода)
public void scrollTo(int position) {
  scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
        scrollView.scrollTo(0, scrollPosition);
     }
  }
}

Comment: Возможно, скролите, когда фрагмент еще не загружен, отсюда и отступ ровно на высоту фрагмента.

Comment: Я попробовала сделать задержку перед скролом в полсекунды, видно, что фрагмент уже появился - но всё равно не скролит :(

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте в `xml` указать `android:layout_gravity="bottom"`.

Comment: scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                scrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
                            }
                        });

Answer (score -1):

```
scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP);
```

Comment: желательно все-таки писать какое-то пояснение

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: основано на опыте , по логике должно вроде FOCUS_DOWN срабатывать но нет FOCUS_UP почему то норм